# How to change Font Color in Unity Lenses and Menus?

Tags: unity, fonts

I installed KDE after Ubuntu and this changed some Fonts in Unity. I followed some advice (i.e. using Compizconfig Settings Manager and other programs, switching themes back and forth) and am almost back to normal in Unity. Only the font and color (very dark grey!) of the Menu Items and the Unity Lenses menus I cant change. I neither have `.fonts` or similar settings in my home folder, nor did I find any setting elsewhere.

Where is this setting?

[image: Screenshot]